# Flat UI proの導入方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails

### 前提

Flat UI pro を購入したのですが、使い方がわかりません
http://designmodo.com/flat
開発環境は Rubymine です。

---

### 発生している問題

`vendor/assets` の javascript と stylesheets に入れてから`assets/javascript` と `assets/stylesheets` で require をすると、下記のエラーが出ました。

そこで、エラー内容の通りに `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( glyphicons-halflings-white.png )` を `config/initializers/assets.rb` に追加しましたが、同じエラーが出ます。

**エラー1**:

```
$ rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=development
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for "font":Sass::Script::Value::String

Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

**エラー2**:
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]